# text overlap in activeReport

Tags: overlap, activereports

with textbox taking data from an sql database.
if the text is long enough it overlap on
the bottom textbox and lines of the table don't adjust.

Comment: after many hours of search i found that each row needs its own vertical line and not one line for all rows

Comment: Right! A control will not grow if there is a control directly adjacent to it. You can also answer your own question below and mark it as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should set "false" to  "MultiLine property" of this textbox .